# Iphone image uploading -- 500 Error

Tags: iphone, ios

I am new to iphone development. I want to share image from my device to server which is handled by myself. I done this in both android as well as from iphone device. Its very well posted from Android, but i get 500 error message from server whenever i posted through iphone. I really dont know where i made mistake. Is there any protocol blocks iphone whenever i communicate with server.

```
NSString *uploadUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"--My url-- "];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:uploadUrl];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSMutableString *m_strUploadedFileName = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"pic_%@_%@.png",dateString,[prefs objectForKey:@"EmailId"]];

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(m_imageFish.image, 0.2);
NSLog(@"image data is %@",imageData);

[request setData:imageData withFileName:m_strUploadedFileName andContentType:@"image/jpg" forKey:@"--server parameter to send-- "];

    [request setDefaultResponseEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];

[request startAsynchronous];
```

Comment: PLease move away from `ASIHTTPRequest` it is nolonger supported, one replacement is [`AFNetworking`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

Comment: @rckoenes whilst yes it is not supported anymore if you are prepared to support it yourself it is still a good service to use, but yes totally agree isn't worth it over using `AFNetworking`